# @Retryable not making retries when triggered by Integration tests In A Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have a simple method in a Service in a SpringBoot Application. I have the retry mechanism setup for that method using @Retryable.
I am trying integration tests for the method in the service and the retries are not happening when the method throws an exception. The method gets executed only once.

```
public interface ActionService { 

@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
public void perform() throws Exception;

}



@Service
public class ActionServiceImpl implements ActionService {

@Override   
public void perform() throws Exception() {

   throw new Exception();
  } 
}



@SpringBootApplication
@Import(RetryConfig.class)
public class MyApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }
}



@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig {

@Bean
public ActionService actionService() { return new ActionServiceImpl(); }

}



@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes= {MyApp.class}) 
@IntegrationTest({"server.port:0", "management.port:0"})
public class MyAppIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private ActionService actionService;

public void testAction() {

  actionService.perform();

}
```

Comment: I don't think `@Retryable` is inherited. Try moving it to the bean service method instead of the interface method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your annotation `@EnableRetry` is at the wrong place, instead of putting it on the `ActionService` interface you should place it with a Spring Java based `@Configuration` class, in this instance with the `MyApp` class. With this change the retry logic should work as expected. Here is a blog post that I had written on if you are interested in more details - http://biju-allandsundry.blogspot.com/2014/12/spring-retry-ways-to-integrate-with.html

Comment: This being a SpringBoot Application, should I have the Service as a bean in the Configuration, apart from the interface itself.   
I have updated the post with my changes. And it still does not work.

Comment: I tested your classes and it worked for me well, the `actionService` was called three times and then returned with an exception, try printing something in your perform method to see it get called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Biju Thanks for putting up a link for this, it helped me to resolve a lot of questions. The only thing that I had to seperately was I still had to add 'retryAdvice' as a bean in the spring xml based approach, Also had to make sure I had context annotation enabled and aspectj is available at classpath. After I added these below I could get it working.

```
    <bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor">
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Comment: `@Configuration` is the same as `<context:annotation-config />`, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is the same as `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` and `@EnableRetry` adds `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. Adding `spring-boot-starter-aop` as a dependency provides `aspectjweaver`.